# Why $urandom is giving same value even with using seed(int or any other) as variable?

Tags: system-verilog

I was using $random to get different number but I need unsigned random number now so I am changing $random to $urandom.

```
module Tb();
   int seed;
   integer num;
  initial begin
      $display("========================================================");
       begin
         $display("$RANDOM: With Seed Value = 2  With Variable");
           seed = 2;
           repeat (5) begin 
             num = $random(seed);
             $display("seed = %d |num  = %d ",seed, num);
           end
       end
      $display ("------------------------------");
       begin
         $display("$U-RANDOM: With Seed Value = 2  With Variable");
           seed = 2;
           repeat (5) begin 
             num = $urandom(seed);
             $display("seed = %d |num  = %d ",seed, num);
           end
       end
      $display ("========================================================");
   end
endmodule
```

These are the results: (As display added in code).

```
========================================================
$RANDOM: With Seed Value = 2  With Variable
seed =      138139 |num  = -2147345408 
seed =   951188000 |num  = -1196295055 
seed =  1784212385 |num  =  -363270956 
seed = -1731404562 |num  =   416079665 
seed = -1607270249 |num  =   540214080 
------------------------------
$U-RANDOM: With Seed Value = 2  With Variable
seed =           2 |num  =  -541627016 
seed =           2 |num  =  -541627016 
seed =           2 |num  =  -541627016 
seed =           2 |num  =  -541627016 
seed =           2 |num  =  -541627016
```

> Expected Results:  Value of seed and num should change in $urandom.
>   As It is changing in case of $random.

Am I missing something about "How $urandom works with seed?" 
In case of $random it is inout port for seed variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of

```
x = $urandom(seed);
```

is equivalent to

```
process p;
p = process::self();
p.srandom(<urandom_seed>);
x = $urandom;
```

The argument to `$urandom` is `input` only, whereas the argument to `$random` is `inout`. This information needs clarification in the LRM. See https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=5902

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `$urandom` *initializes* the generator. That means given an argument, it will always return the same value. The `$urandom(seed)` should be called once and subsequent calls should be called without the seed. 
Example from the 2012 LRM, section 18.13.1:

```
bit [64:1] addr;
bit [ 3:0] number;
addr[32:1] = $urandom( 254 ); // Initialize the generator,
// get 32-bit random number
addr = {$urandom, $urandom }; // 64-bit random number
number = $urandom & 15; // 4-bit random number
```